# How to send nc similar command using python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, netcat, statsd

I am trying to send parameter `foo` and its value to [statsD](https://github.com/etsy/statsd) 
using python (python-2.7) program. When I send packets from command line, using below netcat command, statsD gets value for foo:150 which is correct. 
`echo "foo:150|c" | nc -u -w0 127.0.0.1 8125`

However, when I send `foo:150` through Python program, `statsD` is getting large random values for `foo`, instead of `150`. Python program and `statsD` receive value output is below. Any idea what is error in python program that is causing `statsD` to receive random value, but working perfectly when sending through nc (netcat) command?

**PYTHON PROGRAM:**

```
import socket
import random
UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 8125
while(True):

        MESSAGE = "foo:150|c"       
        #print "message:", MESSAGE

        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                             socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
        sock.sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

**StatsD received value:**

```
timer_data: {},
  counter_rates:
   { 'statsd.bad_lines_seen': 0,
     'statsd.packets_received': 19828,
     'statsd.metrics_received': 19828,
      foo: 2974200 },
  sets: {},
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: can you post error you received?

Comment: I am not receiving any error. It is just I am NOT getting expected value (i.e. 150) of foo in statsD from python program.

Comment: `echo` includes a newline. You don't have that in your python program.Try `MESSAGE = "foo:150|c\n"`

Comment: @JamesKPolk :  I tried `MESSAGE = "foo:150|c\n"` , but still getting random value in statsD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer. Seems like when I changed sending value from counter to as gauges, I am getting correct value. So, I think problem was not in my python program, but it is some logic in `statsD` that was giving me unexpected random values for `foo` when passing as part of counter.

So in short, when I did change from `MESSAGE = "foo:150|c"` to `MESSAGE = "foo:150|g"`, I start getting correct value for `foo`. Below is the output:

```
{ counters:
   { 'statsd.bad_lines_seen': 0,
     'statsd.packets_received': 150383,
     'statsd.metrics_received': 150383 },
  timers: {},
  gauges: { foo: 150, 'statsd.timestamp_lag': 0 },
  timer_data: {},
  counter_rates:
   { 'statsd.bad_lines_seen': 0,
     'statsd.packets_received': 150383,
     'statsd.metrics_received': 150383 },
  sets: {},
```